# Cannot create a vector in RStudio

Tags: r

[image]

I keep getting an error message whenever I want to create a vector using RStudio. I have done the amateur stuff like restarting RStudio and my system.

Comment: Did you create another function called `c`?

Comment: Is there any error if you do `base::c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`? If there isn't any error on this, then it's very likely you've created another function called `c()`, or another package has a function with the same name as `c()`.